# is there any example to make rows in React-virtualized Table(not list) draggable and droppable with React-beautiful-dnd lib?

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-virtualized, react-beautiful-dnd, virtual-table

tried all the methods mention in React-beautiful-dnd lib to make work with virtual list but can't make it work with React-virtualized-table.

Comment: Where you able to solve this integration issue?

Comment: No, there is so many issues positional issues to make both library co-exist with each other, we dropped the idea.

Comment: Anyways, I was able to solve the integration issue. Here is the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116012/react-beautiful-dnd-doesn-t-work-properly-with-react-virtualized-table-component

Comment: Anyways, are there any other issues apart from these?